# Programmatically positioning views in a circle

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibezierpath

I'm wanting to have pre-placed circles orbiting a middle circle when a button is pressed. For example, one middle circle, 5 circles evenly spaced in a circle around the middle circle, and then a button is pressed and they start to orbit around.

I'm using a `BezierPath` and `keyframe` animation to make a single circle orbit around the middle one. I also understand how to add in more circles and make them start at different starting degrees in the animation.

What I don't understand is how to pre-place the circles in the view before the animation has started. The animation isn't running until a button has been pressed, so the orbiting circles need to be at their "starting locations" before the animation starts, ie:

```
let circlePath = UIBezierPath(arcCenter: center, radius: 100, startAngle: 360 / 3, endAngle:CGFloat(M_PI)*2, clockwise: true)
```

the `startAngle`s for each circles would need to be where they already are on the screen before the animation starts.

I can't place the views in the `storyboard` because I don't see any ways to perfectly set the circles at the different degrees around the circle.

What I'm looking for would be something like using the degrees on the circle path and locating that `CGPoint` in the `superview` so I can set the center of my orbiting views on that point. So saying something like :

For the view I want 1/5th of the way on the orbiting circle, grab the `CGPoint` that is 360/72 and then set the `circle.center` to whatever that point is.

I don't know if that's possible? If not what would be another approach to this?